# Shutil ignore_patterns not doing anything

Tags: python-3.x, shutil

I have a script that copies files from a folder to another folder, but I want it to ignore the txt files. I have this code that works, but it does not ignore the txt files. It just copies everything without any warning.

What am I doing wrong?

```
import sys, os, shutil

script, filetobackup = sys.argv
backupdir = r'*path to backupdir*'

def copytree(filetobackup, backupdir, symlinks=False):
        if not os.path.exists(backupdir):
            os.makedirs(backupdir)
        for item in os.listdir(filetobackup):
            s = os.path.join(filetobackup, item)
            d = os.path.join(backupdir, item)
            if os.path.isdir(s):
                shutil.copytree(s, d, symlinks, ignore=ignore_patterns('*.txt'))
            else:
                if not os.path.exists(d) or os.stat(s).st_mtime - os.stat(d).st_mtime > 1:
                    shutil.copy2(s, d)

copytree(filetobackup, backupdir)
```

Edit: Hmm, no one knows?

Comment: what is `ignore_patterns`?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html, shutil.ignore_patterns(*patterns). I don't really get it. I've looked around, but I cannot get any answers why my script does not work. I don't get it :(

Comment: I know what `shutil.ignore_patterns` is I just don't see you importing it so I thought you may have created your own

Comment: I've imported shutil? +1 for trying to help me out though! :)

Comment: Yep but you don't have `shutil.ignore_patterns` so I was unsure, anyway your `shutil.copy2(s, d)` is the issue I think,  if the initial directory has .txt files you never check you just copy, you are only filtering on the copytree call. Does adding `elif item.endswith(".txt"):continue` fix your issue?

Comment: "elif item.endswith(".txt"):continue" does not fix the issue. It only causes syntax error.

Comment: You need to put it after the if and make the else if just elif too

Comment: But my fault, "item" is not supposed to be there since there is no need for it. But I have tried with "elif filetobackup.endwith(".txt"):continue", but I still get syntax error.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hTFesQWB